# Pass URL parameters to swift script

Tags: ios, swift, url, browser, parameters

I did a Swift script that run a .jar by the terminal.

This script is launched when i type "key:" on the browser searchbar, but I need to pass the parameter "key:parameter" written in the URL to the script.

```
import Foundation

@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
   let task = Process()
   task.launchPath = "/users/.../Desktop/MyApp/dist"
   task.launch()
   task.arguments = args
   task.waitUntilExit()
   return task.terminationStatus
}

shell("ls")
shell("java", "-jar", "myApp.jar")
```

How can I store the parameter in a Swift variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us an example? Please post some of your code so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: I edited the question